# Testing a static method which needs to mock a member method and suppress singleton constructor with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I would like to test on a static method (e.g. `HobbyUtil.java:shareReadContext(int lineNumber)` ) which would ask a Singleton class (e.g. `Shelf.java` ) to get an object (e.g. a `Book` ) for further retrieving values (e.g. *lines of context* ) from that returned object.

However, during the mock case execution, the ctor of that Singleton class (i.e. `Shelf.java` ) would trigger several other Singleton classes (e.g. `LibraryA.java` ) in a chain; and one of them would trigger `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`.

I think mocking/spying those irrelevant Singleton classes is out of the spirit of Mock Test as they are irrelevant to my testing scope.

So I decided to suppress the private ctor of this Singleton class (i.e. `Shelf.java` ) and just let the getter method in this class (i.e. `getBook()` ) to return a mocked object with my preferred behavior, which would perfectly match my test case.

The problem I've encountered is that I follow this link to suppress the ctor of **Shelf.java** successfully:
[suppress a singleton constructor in java with powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100816/suppress-a-singleton-constructor-in-java-with-powermock)

but I couldn't figure out the way to let this getter method return what I want properly (i.e. return a mocked object).

The version of *PowerMockito*, *hamcrest* and *JUnit* I am using are listed here for a reference:

```
<dependency><groupId>org.powermock</groupId><artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId><version>1.7.0</version><scope>test</scope></dependency>  
<dependency><groupId>org.powermock</groupId><artifactId>powermock-api-mockit02</artifactId><version>1.7.0</version><scope>test</scope></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId><artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId><version>1.3</version><scope>test</scope></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>junit</groupId><artifactId>junit</artifactId><version>4.12</version><scope>test</scope></dependency>
```

I have also replicated the case with below sample classes to show what I have encountered (HobbyUtilTest.java is the class for my test case):

Supposed there are 5 Java classes in the application:

```
public interface Book {
    public String getContext(int lineNumber);
}
```

```
public class Shelf {

    private static final Shelf shelf = new Shelf();
    private String BOOK_NAME = "HarryPotter";
    private Book book = null;

    private Shelf() {
        book = LibraryA.getInstance().getBook(BOOK_NAME);
        // many relatively complicated logics are here in actual class ... 
        // I want to suppress this ctor 
    }

    public static Shelf getInstance() {
        return shelf;
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;  // I want to return my mocked object while calling this method in test case
    }

}
```

```
public class HobbyUtil {

    public static String shareReadContext(int lineNumber){
        String context = "";
        Book book = Shelf.getInstance().getBook();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < lineNumber; i++) {
            context += book.getContext(i);
        }
        return context;
    }

    private HobbyUtil() {}
}
```

```
public class LibraryA {
    private static final LibraryA library = new LibraryA();
    private Book book;

    private LibraryA() {
        throw new java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError();
    }

    public static LibraryA getInstance() {
        return library;
    }

    public Book getBook(String bookName) {
        return book;
    }
}
```

```
public class BookImpl implements Book{

    private String bookName = null;

    BookImpl(String bookName){
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContext(int lineNumber) {
        return lineNumber + ": Context";
    }
}
```

And I would test the static method `shareReadContext(int lineNumber)` in `HobbyUtil.java` with `HobbyUtilTest.java`

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = { Shelf.class })
public class HobbyUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testShareReadContext() throws Exception {

        Book mockBook = PowerMockito.mock(Book.class);
        when(mockBook.getContext(anyInt())).thenReturn("context for test");

        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(Shelf.class));
        //PowerMockito.spy(Shelf.class);
        //when(Shelf.getInstance().getBook()).thenReturn(mockBook); // does not work
        //PowerMockito.doReturn(mockBook).when(Shelf.getInstance().getBook()); // does not work
        //PowerMockito.when(Shelf.class, "getBook").thenReturn(mockBook); // does not work
        //TODO any approach for it?

        String context = HobbyUtil.shareReadContext(1);
        assertThat(context, is("context for test"));
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help to suggest how could I let the line `Book book = Shelf.getInstance().getBook();` in `HobbyUtil.java` return my mocked object (i.e. `mockBook` )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `Shelf` class is in a package `test`, this should work:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("test.Shelf")
public class HobbyUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testShareReadContext() throws Exception {

        Book book = Mockito.mock(Book.class);
        Mockito.when(book.getContext(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn("context for test");

        Shelf shelf = Mockito.mock(Shelf.class);
        Mockito.when(shelf.getBook()).thenReturn(book);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Shelf.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Shelf.getInstance()).thenReturn(shelf);

        String context = HobbyUtil.shareReadContext(1);
        Assert.assertEquals("context for test", context);
    }
}
```

You'll want to suppress the initialization of the fields of `Shelf` (not only the constructor) and afterwards simply define the appropriate mocks for the `Shelf.getInstance()` (and subsequent) methods.

---

Ps.:

`@SuppressStaticInitializationFor` seems to be equivalent to:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Shelf.class)
public class HobbyUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testShareReadContext() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.fields(Shelf.class));
        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.constructor(Shelf.class));       

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried the approach above and place the Shelf.java in the package 'test', but it would still hit the constructor of `LibraryA` and throws the `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: And I found that no matter using `mock(Shelf.class)` or `spy(Shelf.class)`, due to the class's current design, it would unavoidably hit the ctor and run the implementation in it if the ctor is not suppressed.

Comment: @garykwwong: Strange. I copied all the classes you had in your question into a `test` package and both version of the test are working for me, without the exception.

Comment: You're, right ... sorry that I've forgotten to rename the "test" value to reflect my package name as I thought what you meant was merely the test package of maven. It works fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post an alternative approach here for a reference after searching over other resources again in the meanwhile.

After referencing this site:
https://blog.jayway.com/2009/10/28/untestable-code-with-mockito-and-powermock/

I found that by adding the following line of code to the `TODO` section of original test case could also help to achieve the purpose:

> PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(Shelf.class,
>   "getBook")).toReturn(mockBook);

The downside of this approach is that the method name need to be hard coded as String value, IDE rename automation function would not be effective on this situation.